# Split text while reading line by line

Tags: ruby, file, parsing, split

I am trying to read a text file with contents like this

```
ABC = Thefirststep
XYZ = Secondstep
ABC_XYZ = Finalstep=345ijk!r4+
```

I am able to read the file line by line using this

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
text =  '/tmp/data'
f = File.open(text , "r")
f.each_line { |line|
  puts line
}
f.close
```

What I want to do is have the values `TheFirststep` `Secondstep` and `Finalstep` assigned to separate variables. better if we use split().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
text =  '/tmp/data'
data = []
f = File.open(text , "r")
f.each_line { |line|
  data.push( line.split("=").last)
}
f.close
```

Comment: Its working but seems like if there is another = in the string then the split would fail, would space work in this case ?

Comment: Well, you need to specify the format of all possible lines in the file in order to provide an universal answer. Probably you will need some more logic than the lone "split". Could you clarify the possible lines you can have in the file?

Answer (score 0):

You said you want to, "have the values, 'TheFirststep', 'Secondstep and 'Finalstep' assigned to separate variables.

You cannot create local variables dynamically (not since Ruby v1.8 anyway). That leaves two choices: assign those values to instance variables or use a different data structure, specifically, a hash.

First let's create a data file.

```
data <=-END
ABC = Thefirststep
XYZ    =    Secondstep
ABC_XYZ = Finalstep=345ijk!r4+
END

FName = 'test'
File.write(FName, data)
  #=> 73
```

**Assign values to instance variables**

```
File.foreach(FName) do |line|
  var, value, * = line.chomp.split(/\s*=\s*/)
  instance_variable_set("@#{var.downcase}", value)
end

@abc
  #=> "Thefirststep"
@xyz
  #=> "Secondstep"
@abc_xyz
  #=> "Finalstep"
```

The convention for the names of instance variables (after the `"@"`) is to use [snake-case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case), which is why I downcased them.

**Store the values in a hash**

```
File.foreach(FName).with_object({}) do |line,h|
  var, value, * = line.chomp.split(/\s*=\s*/)
  h[var] = value
end
  #=> {"ABC"=>"Thefirststep", "XYZ"=>"Secondstep", "ABC_XYZ"=>"Finalstep"}
```

As easy as this was to do, it's not generally helpful to generate instance variables dynamically or hashes with dynamically created keys. That's because they are only useful if their values can be obtained and possibly changed, which is problematic.

Note that in

```
var, value, * = line.chomp.split(/\s*=\s*/)
```

`var` equals the first element of the array returned by the split operation, `value` is the second value and `*` discards the remaining elements, if any.